# update excel sheet without Header columns

Tags: c#, excel

I am working on read,write excel sheets.I have an excel sheet to update and unfortunately it does not have header columns.So I am stuck how to update this?

Is it possible to update excel sheet without header? If yes than plz help how to update?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using [excel data reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com) from Codeplex and check how it returns the data set. Also try to manipulate dataset based on your need